# How to prevent onclick event on a div while clicking on body click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to do functionality for body,html elements while clicking on anywhere on document and also there is a div tag which is onclick event will be there. Both are clashing each other how to prevent while clicking on that div. Tried both event stop propagation and event prevent defaul
for example:
jd is nothing but jquery

```
$jd =  jQuery
```

The below event should only triggered particular div. but t his event clashing with body onclick.

```
$jd('.menu-left a').click(function(){
            $jd('.menu-left a').removeClass('active');          
            if($jd(this).hasClass('add_item_team')) self.team.create();
            if($jd(this).hasClass('add_item_qrcode')) self.qrcode.open();
            $jd(this).addClass('active');
            jQuery("#text-lock").trigger("click");
        });

jQuery(document).on('click','body',function(event){
/*console.log("adsfasddfs");   

    var finding_span;
    finding_span = $jd(".design-area").find('.content-inner span.drag-item');

     if(event.target.id == "dg-left"){
     return false;
     }else{
        if(finding_span.length>0){

        console.log("cameeeee");
        design.item.unselect();

        }
     }*/
     var finding_span;
    finding_span = $jd(".design-area").find('.content-inner span.drag-item');

     if(finding_span.length>0){
        design.item.unselect();
    }
```

Comment: do you want to click on a div and not the body? your question is unclear

Comment: use event.preventdefault() and stoppropagation() for preventing event bubbling. Check for preventdefault on internet for more understanding

Comment: what is $jd in above code?

Comment: check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: @KARANLAGALWAR jd is nothing but jquery

Comment: You didn't really post the entire code.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).on('click','body',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
     var finding_span;
    finding_span = $jd(".design-area").find('.content-inner span.drag-item');

     if(finding_span.length>0){
        design.item.unselect();
    }
```

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
   $jd(function(){
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
       $jd('.menu-left a').click(function(){
       $jd('.menu-left a').removeClass('active');          
        if($jd(this).hasClass('add_item_team')) self.team.create();
        if($jd(this).hasClass('add_item_qrcode')) self.qrcode.open();
        $jd(this).addClass('active');
        jQuery("#text-lock").trigger("click");
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).on('click','html,body,#main',function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();


    if(event.target.id=="text-lock"){
        return false;

    }

     var finding_span;
    finding_span = $jd(".design-area").find('.content-inner span.drag-item');

     if(finding_span.length>0){
        design.item.unselect();

        jQuery(".add_item_text").css({'background-color':'#f6f6f6','color':'#333'});
    }
```