# button and body onclick event triggering at same time

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

```js
angular.element('body').on('click', function () {
        //  $('.dropdown-menu').hide();
    console.log("clicked outside");
        });
```

```js
$scope.showDropdown = function (e) {
      $scope.filterClick = !$scope.filterClick;
      e.stopPropagation();
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-append-to-body" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
        ng-click="showDropdown()">
    <img src="assets/images/filterIcon.png">
    &nbsp&nbspFilter <span class="caret"></span>
</button>

  <li class="nav-item dropdown" ng-hide="filterClick">
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="item in items">
          <div class="filter-class">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </li>
```

I have button click and body click functionality. But if I print any value in console at the time of body click, it is working fine. But the same functionality is working for button click also.

My Need is,

1) If I click button, body onclick should not trigger. Only button onclick should work.

2) on click of button, filter dropdown is opening. And when I click the same buttoin again it  is closing. (toggle)

3) But when i click outside anywhere, I want to hide that dropdown. But it is not working.

How can I do this using angularjs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent onclick event on a div while clicking on body click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302672/how-to-prevent-onclick-event-on-a-div-while-clicking-on-body-click)

Comment: Your HTML does not have a body tag. Please make a runnable snippet without any errors

Answer (score 1):

Pass through $event on ng-click in child i.e. button and then stopPropagation() on the event in the child method. StopPropagation stops event bubbling.

HTML

```
    <div ng-click='parentClick()'>
        <button ng-click="childClick($event)">Click Me</button>
    </div>
```

JS

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.parentClick = function() {
            alert('Parent clicked');
        };
        $scope.childClick = function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            alert('Child clicked');
        };
    }
```

Comment: It is working. But after clicking parentClick, dropdown is not opening. If I click second time then it is working. But not in single click.

Comment: @sathishkumar understood. Use ng-if versus ng-show or ng-hide. The issue is with the way you manipulating the DOM which is why it is recommended to use directives, but in your case the easy way around is ng-if which will effectively "reset" the DOM. So  ng-if="!filterClick" or  ng-if="filterClick"

Answer (score 0):

Use event.stopPropagation() in child button element callback function .

```
angular.element('#btn-append-to-body').on('click', function () {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @Avhijit | it is always better to include some code snippet and source(if possible) in support of your answer...

Comment: This will only work if jQuery has been loaded. `angular.element` does not support CSS selectors out of the box.